# Как сделать условие на то что массив состоит только из нулей?

Tags: c#

Как сделать "изящно" условие на то что массив состоит только из нулей?

Comment: в чем измеряется изящность?

Comment: самым оптимальным будет всё таки перебор всех элементов и проверка их на ==0.

Answer (score 7):

Например с помощью метода [All](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
bool onlyZero = arr.All(el=> el == 0);
```

Comment: Но вопрос - а если нет элементов в массиве, то считать ли, что массив состоит из нулей?

Comment: @SanŚ́́́́Ý́́́́Ś́́́́ если по логике, то да считать именно так. Также как площадь несуществующей фигуры считать равной 0. Противоречия здесь нет, однако если принципиально что массив не должен быть пуст, тогда нужно кидать исключение, потому как bool подразумевает либо "да все нули", либо "нет, есть отличные от нуля". Можно конечно возвращать ?bool и null если массив пуст, но это совсем изврат.

Answer (score 1):

Ну чтобы прям изящно и хардкорно, то не тру юзать LINQ

Хочешь кого-то удивить? 
То вот так самое то

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] arr = new [] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] arr1 = new [] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] arr2 = new [] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
        int[] arr3 = new [] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };


        Console.WriteLine(IsAllZero(0, arr) ? "All are 0" : "Bad array");
        Console.WriteLine(IsAllZero(0, arr1) ? "All are 0" : "Bad array");
        Console.WriteLine(IsAllZero(0, arr2) ? "All are 0" : "Bad array");
        Console.WriteLine(IsAllZero(0, arr3) ? "All are 0" : "Bad array");
    }

    static bool IsAllZero(int findEl, int[] arr)
    {
        int el = findEl, i = arr.Length;

        while ( i --> 0 && (el |= arr[i]) == findEl);

        return el == findEl;
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
All are 0
Bad array
Bad array
Bad array
```

Запускаемый пример https://dotnetfiddle.net/zbW1jU

Comment: ну вот, а потом вопросы появляются: что это за оператор `-->`? :-D В этом варианте, кстати, для пустого массива всегда `true`

Comment: прикольно, только читать такой код можно только один раз, для того чтобы переписать в нормальный вид. Никогда не понимал использования странных конструкций разрешенных синтаксически, но полностью убивающих читаемость кода. Ничего личного, просто реально не понимаю зачем это делать, если на выходе результат не отличается.

Comment: Grundy, верно, а вот rdorn ничего не понял, видимо))

Comment: Rdorn, тут нет одной страной конструкции ;)

Comment: @SanŚ́́́́Ý́́́́Ś́́́́, rdorn имел в виду, что такие конструкции убивают читаемость алгоритма. И правда, чтобы разобраться в методе IsAllZero придется вчитаться в условие while, еще который и с пустым телом. Такие сложности лучше в продакшене не использовать.
А так да, красиво выглядит.

Comment: @nuts119, конечно, до прода такое не доводить )

Answer (score 1):

Самое правильное и изящное решение — конечно, через LINQ. Но если хочется руками в сишном стиле, то проще всего наверное так:

```
bool IsAllZeroes(int[] arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) 
        if (arr[i] != 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Пустой массив подходит: все его элементы — нули.